# Inverse for the word "define"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

Is there a word that is the inverse of "define"? Like taking a definition and giving the word?

For example. If you said "The action of propelling one self from a surface using leg muscles", and I said "Jump", I would have done *this*.

Comment: You would have **identified** the word "jump". But that's always supposing there *is* a word meeting the definition - a single correct one, at that, otherwise you could only suggest a possible answer. If I'd said "The action of propelling one self from a surface using **arm** muscles" you couldn't identify the word. You might **guess** "brachiate", but who's to say whether ***I*** would accept that as "the correct answer"? I'm not sure this is a constructive question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your comments sounds like a fine answer.

Comment: @Mark Beadles: I refrained from voting to close on the off-chance there's a word more specifically fitting OP's concept. I don't really approve of these *"please identify the word matching my description"* questions anyway. It's just turning ELU into a human-powered [reverse dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't it just be as simple as the word *name*? You have *named* the thing being described.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/name

Comment: +1 *Name* would be my answer of choice.

Answer (score 1):

To mention a word that agrees with a definition is (in my opinion) to *[particularize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/particularize)*, *[specialize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/specialize)*, *[manifest](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/manifest#Verb)*, *[embody](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embody#Verb)*, or *[incarnate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incarnate)* (sense 4) that definition.

Answer (score -1):

*Breviloquentify*? Cf. *breviloquence*.

eta: after MetaEd's feedback.  Breviloquence is a rather obscure term for speaking in a brief and pertinent mode.  I suggest breviloquentify as a possible verb form (to make breviloquent) but would advise against it unless you explain the word as you use it.  In normal Englsih I would just use the phrase "the word for..."

Comment: given that neither word is easily understood, could you perhaps add a definition?

Comment: "A brief and pertinent mode of speaking."  to summarize a few online dictionaries.  From Latin with roots brevis +‎ loquentia i.e brief and speaking.

Comment: -1 OP wants the word for it, not the word for his prose after using the result of doing it.

Comment: @ΜετάEd  - perhaps you'd like to take a wild guess at what the "-ify" suffix does to a noun?

Comment: Apologies. Ed is right that this is not a helpful answer in terms of this sites goals.